# Determine all real numbers that can be eigenvalues of operator A.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

**Problem**:

Let $A$ be some linear operator such that:
$$ (A^{2006}-I)^{2006}-I=0. $$
Determine all real numbers that can be eigenvalues of operator $A$.

**Question**: How to solve this problem?

**My attempt**:

$(A^{2006}-I)^{2006}-I=0 \implies (A^{2006}-I)^{2006}=I \implies det((A^{2006}-I)^{2006})=1 \implies [det(A^{2006}-I)]^{2006} = 1$

$A^{2006} - I = (A-x_1I)...(A-x_{2006}I) \implies [det(A-x_1I)...det(A-x_{2006}I)]^{2006}=1$

Let's say that $A$ can have $n$ real eigenvalues and let's call them $\lambda_j$ ($j=1,...n$). That means $det(A-\lambda_jI)=0$. From this follow that no eigenvalue can be $x_j$ ($j=1,...2006$). That means that real numbers which satisfy equation $x^{2006}=1$ can not be eigenvalues. But it would seem to me that my "solution" is incomplete, for how do I know that there are no more restrictions on eigenvalues? And in my attempt I prejudiced that there is finate number $n$ of eigenvalues, how do I know there is not infinitley many eigenvalues?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Is $p(\lambda)$ an eigenvalue of $p(A)$? ($p(\cdot)$ denotes a polynomial.)

Comment: Thanks for help. Does that theorem hold if functions $p$ is not polynomial? If not in general, what conditions must we put on $p$ so that it holds?

Comment: Well, $p$ can be any entire function or more generally, function which is analytic on a neighborhood of the spectrum of $A$. (A bit of knowledge on complex analysis may be needed to fully understand the concepts.) Under these conditions, $p(A)$ can be rigorously defined and $p(\lambda)$ are exactly all eigenvalues of $p(A)$. It is called the spectral mapping theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is an eigenvalue it must satisfy $(x^{2006}-1)^{2006}-1=0$, so $x^{2006}-1$ is a $2006^{th}$ root of $1$.  The only reals that satisfy that are $\pm 1$.  We can have $x=0$ or $x^{2006}=2, x=\pm2^{1/2006}$